# NSString writeToFile with URL encoded string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsstring

I have a Mac application that keeps it's own log file. It appends info to the file using NSString's writeToFile method. One of the things that it logs are URL's of web services that it is interacting with. To encode the URL, I'm doing this:

```
searchString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)searchString, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

The app then appends searchString to the rest of the URL and writes it to the log file. Now the problem is that after adding that URL encoding line, nothing seems to be getting written to the file. The program functions as expected otherwise however. Removing the line of code above results in all of the correct information being logged to the file (removing that line is not an option because searchString must be URL encoded).

Oh and I am using NSUTF8StringEncoding when writing the NSString to the file.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I know there's also a similar function to CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes in NSString, but I've read that it doesn't always work. Can anyone shed some light on this if my original question cannot be answered? Thanks! (EDIT: same problem occurs when using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`)

EDIT 2: Here's the code that I'm using to append messages to the log file.

```
+(void)logText:(NSString *)theString{
    NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Folder/File.log"];
    NSString *fileContents = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];
    if([fileContents lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] >= 204800){
        fileContents = @"";
    }
    NSString *timeStamp = [[NSDate date] description];
    timeStamp = [timeStamp stringByAppendingString:@": "];
    timeStamp = [timeStamp stringByAppendingString:theString];
    fileContents = [fileContents stringByAppendingString:timeStamp];
    fileContents = [fileContents stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    [fileContents writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Side comment: it's odd that you are reading and writing the entire contents of the file just to append a string at the end. As for your problem, I still haven't detected a reason for why your code works without the `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` transformation but doesn't if you add it. Are you able to reproduce the problem as a small SenTestingKit unit test that you could post here (and which doesn't rely on any of your own code, so others can try it; perhaps use a separate new Xcode project)?

Comment: Yead, I wrote that code in my very early days of Cocoa, perhaps I should make some changes. I just tried making a test project and everything worked as expected. I can't imagine what part of my code would be causing this. Is it possible that the actual text that is being logged is causing the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid that unless you can post enough of your code or other instructions here for someone else to reproduce the problem on their own machine, this is turning too much into a remote debugging session, which isn't the purpose of this site. I can only offer you generic advice at this point: use the Xcode debugging tools, or add some `NSLog` to your code. As you say the code works without the encode URL line, I'd put a breakpoint or `NSLog(@"Encoded: %@", searchString)` right after that and maybe `NSLog(@"Logging: %@", theString)` at the start of `logText:`.

Comment: I found the problem. It had to do with the way that I was writing the NSString to the file. I was using NSString's `writeToFile:` but I switched to NSFileHandle and now everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after almost a whole day no one else has offered any answers, I'm going to post a wild guess here: you're not accidentally using the string you want to output (with percent characters in it) as a *format string* are you?

That is, making the mistake of doing:

`NSLog(@"In format strings you can use %@ as a placeholder for an object, and %i for a plain C integer.")`

Instead of:

`NSLog(@"%@", @"In format strings you can use %@ as a placeholder for an object, and %i for a plain C integer.");`

But I'm going to be surprised if this turns out to be the cause of your problem, as it usually causes random-looking output, rather than absolutely no output. And in some cases, Xcode also gives compiler warnings about it (when I tried `NSLog(myString)`, I got "warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments").

So don't shoot me down if this answer doesn't help. It would be easier to answer your question if you could show us more of your logging code. As for the one line you provided, I can't detect anything wrong with it.

**Edit:** Oops, I kind of missed that you mentioned you're using `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` to write the string to the file, so it's even more unlikely you're accidentally treating it as a format string somewhere. But I'm going to leave this answer up for now. Again, you should really show us more of your code though ...

**Edit:** Regarding your question on a method in NSString that has similar percent encoding functionality, that would be `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`. I'm not sure what kind of problems you're thinking of when you say you've heard it doesn't always work. But one thing is that `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` allows you to specify extra characters that don't normally have to be escaped but which you still want to be escaped, while the method of NSString doesn't allow you to specify this.

Comment: I'll try `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` and see if it causes any problems.

Comment: It appears that using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` also results in nothing being logged to the file. I'll add some more code to my original post.