# Object Oriented question

Tags: c++, objective-c, object

I recently gave in a piece of coursework and my teacher said that my approach is wrong and I got marks taken off. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I did wrong and how I can fix this.. (ignore the syntax but the idea is there, this was in objective c but I guess the same principle would apply)

```
main class()
{

int variable1; 
int variable2; 
int variable3; 

CalculationClass object1; 
variable3 = object1.calculate(variable1,variable2); 

}

CalculationClass()
{
           int calculate(int a, int b)
           {
              int c;
              c = a+b;
              return c;
           }
}
```

In the feedback the teacher said that my approach to object orientated is wrong. Because I don't have any variables in the calculation class, I could of just put everything inside the main class and call it from there.

Is this true? How can this be fixed? (do I just put variables inside the calculation class..? - I found it easier just to pass variables though the parameters).

thanks for any help

Comment: You are using the object like a namespace. However Java takes this approach all the time, so I wouldn't say you should have lost marks over it.

Comment: I am guessing the teacher's point was rather than use a separate class "CalculateClass", you could have just as easily created a method on class main to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: The teacher lost a teaching moment.  Marking someone down without explaining why that means and why it might be incorrect is just following dogma.  No learning there.

Comment: Yes there is learning. The person himself is doing the learning now. Chop chop! (agreed partially on the teaching moment; a teacher must pick his teaching moments to begin with :))

Comment: Doesn't objective C provide vanilla functions ? I fail to see why we need a class here.

Comment: @user648244: It seems you forgot to mention the most important thing: what was the task you were solving with this code? (If the task was to add two int variables then your teacher is right: just put `a+b` to main() function without any classes and other garbage). Was this supposed to be an example of object oriented programming or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the assignment that was given to you is of a functional nature.

Naturally, your solution steered towards a functional solution and away from artificial object-orientation that was required on top.

You could put the solution in a "true" object-oriented garment like your teacher requires (putting variables into the class) but is not natural in my opinion.

Comment: I'd say there's ambiguity in the question as to whether the teacher wanted an OO approach to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

your teacher might not be totally right,

in OOP we have something called 'static class' which doesn't contain 
instance level properties (dynamic properties), 
the same way as you implement the code above,

this static class contains shared methods which are used by other classes

for example in pseudo code:

```
//class for translating phrases
class translator {

  static string translate(string phrase,string destination_language) {
    //return the 'phrase' in 'destination_language'
  }
}
```

Comment: In C++ (and perhaps also in Objective C, I don't know), one uses a garden variety function here. In languages which stupidly disallow free functions (Java, C#), you have to resort to the "my class is in fact a namespace" idiom (that you call "static class"). Usually I take this as a code smell, but sometimes it cannot be avoided.

Comment: I'm with @Alexandre here. Some language designers believe that forbidding free functions is what makes their language "object oriented". It is not!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Peter G. this is a functional nature problem, I believe. Nevertheless, another solution would be to create a class Number, an int wrapper with methods for calculations and other conversions, functionalities you might need.

Example:

```
Number num1 = Number(variable1);
Number num2 = Number(variable2);
Number num3;

num3 = num1.plus(num2); //Personally I believe this looks more OOP ;)
```

Which would be implemented somehow like this:

```
class Number(){
    int var;

    Number(int v){var = v;}//constructor

    Number plus(Number otherNum){//calculation
        return Number(this.var + otherNum.var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor would probably like you to be able to write

```
object3.calculate(object1, object2);
```

not just put a function inside a class and call that object oriented.

```
class Calculations
{
     int calculate(int a, int b);
}
```

isn't any more "object oriented" than

```
namespace Calculations
{
    int calculate(int a, int b);
}
```

Comment: Some people obviously disagree.  :-) Care to comment?

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but I can see why your answer was down-voted as it doesn't really make clear how the original poster should address the teacher's criticism.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Right, I don't want to do his assignment for him. :-) I pointed out what's wrong with the original attempt, and some of the proposed solutions, hoping he/she would draw some conclusions from that. And perhaps learn something?

Comment: Ah, I see now. :) I would suggest to add an explanative disclaimer when you post an incomplete or possibly incorrect answer on purpose. I recently did something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494133/nsstring-writetofile-with-url-encoded-string/5507008#5507008. In your case, something like "I don't want to give you a full answer because it's a course assignment, but here's a hint so that you can hopefully figure it out on your own and learn something." It helps prevent "what was this guy thinking posting *that* as an answer?!"-downvotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more like what your teacher could have wanted (in pseudo-OOP language):

```
class Computation
{
    private int a, b;

    public Computation(int a_, int b_)
    {
        a = a_; b = b_;
    }

    public int compute()
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int v1, v2;
    ...
    Computation c(v1, v2);
    v3 = c.compute();
}
```

The point here is that the class `Computation` could be constructed from various different ways, but called always the same way (and eg. be replaced at run time by another object which computes a different way). This is the "functor" idiom.